# Configuring MongoDB + doctrine in Symfony

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine, symfony-2.0

I was trying to install MongoDB doctrine bundle as written in [here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/index.html#installation)
But when I ran the command

> `$ php bin/vendors install`

It throws up the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>
> `Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Configuration::setLoggerCallable()`in
>
> `C:\wamp\www\Symfony\app\cache\dev\appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 245`

I have followed the installation instructions to the word (which has not been much anyways...) and i have also double checked my installation... Is there something I am missing here?

**Update** : A similar problem [is mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7985248/doctrinemongodbbundle-getting-a-fatal-error-in-symfony2), but even after following the answer there, i could not successfully configure DoctrineMongoDBBundle.

Answer (score 0):

The latest changes in the Doctrine MongoDB repo have introduces this problem. To stick to a version before this happened, add this line to `deps.lock`:

```
doctrine-mongodb 5ccb18231218ce92c9d72295f69bebfe172ef5fb
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work for me...
btw, after a little more digging, i found a similar problem, refer to the updated question...

Comment: These are two different problems, and you need to do what I wrote here as well as what I wrote in an answer to [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7985248/doctrinemongodbbundle-getting-a-fatal-error-in-symfony2). Don't forget to run `bin/vendors install` after you do these.

Comment: I was getting the above mentioned error on running the `bin/vendors install` command. The issue seems to have finally been resolved.

Thanks for your time elnur.

Answer (score 0):

Well, finally I managed to solve it by adding this to the `deps` file:

```
[DoctrineMongoDBBundle]
    git=http://github.com/symfony/DoctrineMongoDBBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Symfony/Bundle/DoctrineMongoDBBundle
    version=origin/2.0
```

** note the

```
version=**origin**/2.0
```

which is different from the previously suggested simple

```
version=2.0.0 or something similar...
```

*I have a hunch that this problem occurs only on Windows, I hope someone could kindly confirm this.*